# Scraping lists of elements using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

The html part that I want to **scrape** is as follows:

```
<ul . . .> #has some attributes represented by dots
<li . . .>
<div class="c1">
    <h4 class="c2">T1</h4>
    <h5 class="c3">T2</h5>
    <p class="c4">T3</p>
    <p class="c5">T4</p>

</div>
</li>
<li . . .>
<div class="c1">
    <h4 class="c2">T1</h4>
    <h5 class="c3">T2</h5>
    <p class="c4">T3</p>
    <p class="c5">T4</p>
</div>

</li>
<li> . . .</li>
.  .  .
.  .  .
.  .  .   # dots show repetition
</ul>
```

Now I want to get the texts from `h4`, `h5`, `p`,`p` in the `div` class `c1` inside the `li` lists. I solved this problem using selenium as below:

```
pare = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='c1']")
for par in pare:
        title = par.find_element_by_xpath("./h4[@class='c2']")
        manu = par.find_element_by_xpath("./h5[@class='c3']")
        desc = par.find_element_by_xpath("./p[@class='c4']")
        tit.append(title.text)
        man.append(manu.text)
        des.append(desc.text)
```

Now in beautifulsoup I used the following code but it did not work as it prints the empty lists:

```
titles = soup.find_all("h4","WideSidebarProductList-item-title")
manufacturers = soup.find_all("h5","WideSidebarProductList-item-manufacturer")
descriptions = soup.find_all("p","WideSidebarProductList-item-description")
prices = soup.find_all("p","WideSidebarProductList-item-price")

for i,t in enumerate(titles):
    tit.append(t.get_text(strip=True))
    man.append(manufacturers[i].get_text(strip=True))
    des.append(descriptions[i].get_text(strip=True))
    pri.append(prices[i].get_text(strip=True))
```

The lists are printed empty. Please help me solve this issue as I am new to beautifulsoup.

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

```
my_divs = soup.find_all('div', {'c1'})
titles = [h for div in my_divs for h in div.find_all("h4")]
manufacturers = [h for div in my_divs for h in div.find_all("h5")]
descriptions = [p for div in my_divs for p in div.find_all("p")]
prices = [p for div in my_divs for p in soup.find_all("p")]


man = [item.get_text(strip=True) for item in manufacturers]
tit = [item.get_text(strip=True) for item in titles]
des = [item.get_text(strip=True) for item in descriptions]
pri = [item.get_text(strip=True) for item in prices]
```

Comment: `list index out of range` error while accessing `manufacturers[i]`. I want to scrap the crosssite references from this link 
https://www.arrow.com/en/products/lmk107bbj475mklt/taiyo-yuden
Maybe the link will help you

Comment: You can search the cross refernces in the the page and inspect elements there and maybe help me

Comment: How can I just look inside the div element to search for these elements because there are other p or h5,h4 tags on the page as well. Or how could I assign a class to them

Comment: I think you should ask other question in SO

Comment: I particularly mentioned the classes in the question. That is because I wanted to scrap elements with just those classes. Its the same question and I am looking for a complete answer.

Comment: c2, c3, c4, c5 == titles, manufacturers, descriptions, prices ?

Comment: I understand what you are doing and it should work fine but the result of 
`my_divs = soup.find_all('div', {'c1'})` is an empty list. here `c1 = 'WideSidebarProductList-item-details'`

Comment: I cant understand why it is showing empty list although these tags with these particular classes are present in the page. Can u plz check the link(2nd comment) again to see if I am explaining anything wrong. Thanks for the answer by the way

Comment: I got it. It is actually an Ajax loaded element so that's why it could not be scrapped using requests. Thanks for the help by the way.